# Why does Unicode.org no longer offer a reference UTF-8/16/32 converter?

Tags: unicode

A reference converter from UTF-8/16/32 in C used to be available at ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/PROGRAMS/CVTUTF/. This included the files ConvertUTF.h and ConvertUTF.c.

It was freely available and is incorporated into many open source projects.  It's even recommended in Microsoft documentation: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q232580/

But now it's gone! What's the story? Can is still be legally used? Was there a problem with it?

Comment: You might want to ask this question to the Unicode mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is hinted at [here](http://unicode.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=90). In short, it was unmaintained, buggy and not kept up to date to the latest Unicode version, thus it was retired.

Comment: in case the linked unicode.org topic disappears,  the suggested replacement is 'ICU' project  http://site.icu-project.org/download